# How to show firebase realtime data to Process Bar

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to show realtime firebase data to my process bars,
can anyone help me? Please I'm so stuck. This is my data:
[image]

And this is my processbar: [image]

My Code:

```js
  <script>
      // Firebase Tinggi Air
        var dbref_pakan = firebase.database();
        dbref_pakan.ref("tinggi").on("value", function(snapshot) {
        var tinggi_awal = data.val();
        var tinggi_pakan = tinggi_awal.pakan;
        var tinggi_air = "0." + tinggi_awal.air;
        });
  </script>
      <script>
          // entah
      var obtained = 75;
      var total = 150;
      var percent = obtained*100/total;
      var percentage = "0." + percent;
        
        let options = {
          startAngle: -1.55,
          size: 150,
          value: percentage,
          fill: {gradient: ['#315ACD', '#4E75E2']}
          
        }
        $(".circle .bar").circleProgress(options).on('circle-animation-progress',
        function(event, progress, stepValue){
          $(this).parent().find("span").text(String(stepValue.toFixed(2).substr(2)) + "%");
        });
        $(".react .bar").circleProgress({
          value: tinggi_air
        });
      </script>
```

I put "percentage" value in "value:" and it worked, "but tinggi_air" didn't work, instead it followed the value from var percentage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the values using a snapshot listener while also exporting the values externally. Currently, you have them declared inside the function but not returning it to the loading bar

I don't have the full scope of the loading bar you are using, so I made some assumptions but in general, this is what you should be looking at

```js
<script>
      var obtained = 75;
      var total = 150;
      var percent = obtained*100/total;
      var percentage = "0.0";

      var percent_pakan;
      var percent_air;



      // Firebase Tinggi Air
        const listener = firebase.database().ref("tinggi")
        .on("value", (snapshot) => {
            var data = data.val();
            percent_pakan = data.pakan;
            percent_air= "0." + data.air;
        });

        
        let options = {
          startAngle: -1.55,
          size: 150,
          value: percent_pakan,
          fill: {gradient: ['#315ACD', '#4E75E2']}
          
        }
        $(".circle .bar").circleProgress(options).on('circle-animation-progress',
        function(event, progress, stepValue){
          $(this).parent().find("span").text(String(stepValue.toFixed(2).substr(2)) + "%");
        });
        $(".react .bar").circleProgress({
          value: percent_air
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it doesn't work yet, maybe it's javascript from the loading bar, thank u before. ☺️ Btw I already got the answer, I will upload it here.

Comment: Can I ask again? Hehehe this is about using if else in Firebase

Comment: Sure, what do you need?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68646907/if-else-condition-with-realtime-firebase-value
Please help me :')

Answer (score 0):

```js
        // Progress Bar START
        var tinggi = database.ref("tinggi");
        var tinggi_awal = 0;
        var tinggi_air = "0.0";
        var tinggi_pakan = "0.0";

        tinggi.on("value", function (data) {
          tinggi_awal = data.val();
          tinggi_pakan = "0." + tinggi_awal.pakan;
          tinggi_air = "0." + tinggi_awal.air;
          console.log(tinggi_air);

          let optionsPakan = {
            startAngle: -1.55,
            size: 150,
            value: tinggi_pakan,
            fill: { gradient: ['#315ACD', '#4E75E2'] }
          }

          let optionsAir = {
            startAngle: -1.55,
            size: 150,
            value: tinggi_air,
            fill: { gradient: ['#315ACD', '#4E75E2'] }
          }

          $(".circle-pakan .bar").circleProgress(optionsPakan).on('circle-animation-progress',
            function (event, progress, stepValue) {
              $(this).parent().find("span").text(String(stepValue.toFixed(2).substr(2)) + "%");
            });

          $(".circle-air .bar").circleProgress(optionsAir).on('circle-animation-progress',
            function (event, progress, stepValue) {
              $(this).parent().find("span").text(String(stepValue.toFixed(2).substr(2)) + "%");
            });
        });
        // Progress Bar END

      }
```