# If/else condition with Realtime firebase value

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wanted to ask, is it possible to use if/else on firebae's realtime results, which is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEJPZ.png)

```
if (Recent === waktu) {
   Hasil : "1";
} else {
   Hasil : "0";
}
```

This is my failed code:

```js
                    // Eksekusi Jadwal
    var waktu_jadwal = firebase.database().ref();
    return waktu_jadwal.on('value').then((snapshot)=>{
      return snapshot.forEach(jadwal_waktu=>{
            if (jadwal_waktu.child("waktu").val() === (jadwal_waktu.child("Recent").val()) {
             waktu_jadwal.update ({
               Keadaan: {
                 Hasil: 1
               }
             });
            } else {
              waktu_jadwal.update ({
               Keadaan: {
                 Hasil: 0
               }
             });
            }
            return console.log("added");
            })

        })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `if/else` as you have, as this is a callback function and will run like any other part of your script. Just be aware that you are using `.on()` which is an active firebase listener, if you intend on getting the value once, there is `.once()`.

I would be cautious of shadowing variable names
try a more relative name such as 'Key'

```js
                return snapshot.forEach(Key=>{
                if (Key.child("waktu").val() === (Key.child("Recent").val()) {
                 waktu_jadwal.update ({
```

You can also convert the object from snapshot data to a son object with
`const data = snapshot.toJSON();`

Comment: Can you write the full code? I'm a bit confused

Comment: Is it like that? I replaced some of the code in the question according to your answer.

Comment: it seems you deleted the request to fetch the data: Firebase creates a reference to service endpoints, of which you can call your respective methods to get or set data. Your code before appeared fine besides the shadowed name, if there are specific issues with getting the data, we can look into it deeper

Comment: is it like that? 

Comment: pretty much, I would have to test it myself and console log it. But as I read it, you are declaring a reference, then fetching the reference data (snapshot listener) then on the listener callback, `(.then(snapshot))` you are responding to internal values. 
 if something isn't working as expected, make sure you console.log it's value and `typeof`

Comment: just make sure you are handling the return correctly, since you are not awaiting it - it will return a promise object

Comment: Still not working :')
May I give you my file and you edit it, and I add you as admin in my firebase project?

Comment: sure, my email: digimbyte@gmail.com

Comment: It's been added, and I've sent the file to your email :) . Thanks

Comment: I emailed you. :)